# how to highlight picklist values with color in visualforce pdf page

Tags: visualforce

```
<tr>
     <td width="100%" colspan="18" ><table style="width:100%;" class="tr2"> 
           <tr style="font-size:10px;vertical-align:middle;">
                              <td width="20%" height="25px" style="text-align:center;border-left:hidden;">&nbsp;<b>Task Category</b>
                <apex:OutputText value="{!jobSafety.Task__c}" 
                   styleClass="{if(Record.Task__c == "Ind-Agriculture","background-color:#FFCC33;",if(Record.Task__c == "Auto-Truck-Bus","background-color:#FFCC33;"))}"/>  
                  </td>   
              <td width="20%" height="25px" style="text-align:center;" >&nbsp;Ind-Agriculture </td>    
              <td width="20%" height="25px" style="text-align:center;" >&nbsp;Auto-Truck-Bus</td> 
         <td width="20%" height="25px" style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;Ind-Other </td>   
        <td  width="20%" height="25px" style="border-right: 1px solid white; text-align:center;">&nbsp;Fire Pump </td>  </tr></table></td>
 </tr>
```

i am using output text to highlight values based on if condition but i am getting output text must have end tag but the end tag is already there

Comment: You are missing an exclamation mark in the `styleClass` definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"` character is being used as a delimiter in Visualforce so can't be used in the body of e.g.:

```
styleClass="{! if(Record.Task__c == "Ind-Agriculture"...
```

as the page processor thinks the second `"` it gets to is the end of the expression string for the `styleClass` attribute.

One solution is to switch to the alternate `'` string delimiter inside the expression:

```
styleClass="{! if(Record.Task__c == 'Ind-Agriculture'...
```

**PS**

And to quote sfdcfox (and Ranga): "Don't forget the `!`".

Comment: Don't forget the `!`.

Comment: @sfdcfox I certainly had...

Comment: Also make sure applybodytag attribute set false in page tag.